# Swift static library compile fails with "Stack dump without symbol names" when build with release configuration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

#### Situation

As I described in title, Swift static library below fails when it's built with **release** build configuration. It's okay when built with *debug* configuration.
[image]

#### Codes

It's part of my project codes where the error occurs. If you try compiling it in a static library project, you can also get the error I got.

```
public struct LocalStorageManager<Instance, Storage> where Instance: Codable, Storage: StorageType {
    private let localStorage: Storage
    private let coderSet: CoderSet
    
    public func save(_ instance: Instance, name: String) -> URL? {
        guard let data = try? coderSet.encoder.encode(instance) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return localStorage.save(data: data, name: name)
    }
    
    public func load(path: URL) -> Instance? {
        guard let data = localStorage.download(with: path) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let instance = try? coderSet.decoder.decode(Instance.self, from: data) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return instance
    }
    
    public init(_ localStorage: Storage = LocalStorageService()) {
        self.localStorage = localStorage
        self.coderSet = CoderSet()
    }
}

fileprivate struct CoderSet {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
}


struct LocalStorageService: StorageType {
    private let storage: FileManager
    
    init(_ storage: FileManager = FileManager.default) {
        self.storage = storage
    }
    
    func save(data: Data, name: String?) -> URL? {
        guard let name else { return nil }
        
        do {
            let filePath = fileURL(with: name)
            try data.write(to: filePath ?? URL(string: "www.google.com")!)
            
            return filePath
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func download(with url: URL) -> Data? {
        do {
            guard storage.fileExists(atPath: url.relativeString) else {
                return nil
            }
            
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


extension LocalStorageService {
    var documentDirectory: URL? {
        return try? self.storage.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                     in: .userDomainMask,
                                     appropriateFor: nil,
                                     create: false)
    }
    
    func fileURL(with name: String?) -> URL? {
        guard let documentDirectory = documentDirectory else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let parsedName = name ?? UUID().uuidString
        
        return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(parsedName)
    }
}


public protocol StorageType {
    func save(data: Data, name: String?) -> URL?
    func download(with url: URL) -> Data?
}
```

#### Error logs

[image]
The codes show error logs like:

```
SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ CompileFailureTestFramework.swift /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework.swift (in target 'CompileFailureTestFramework' from project 'CompileFailureTestFramework')
    cd /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework
    builtin-swiftTaskExecution -- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework.swift -emit-module-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftsourceinfo -emit-dependencies-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-master.d -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-master.dia -emit-objc-header-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-Swift.h -emit-abi-descriptor-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.abi.json -target arm64-apple-ios16.2-simulator -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk -I /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -no-color-diagnostics -g -module-cache-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -O -serialize-debugging-options -enable-bare-slash-regex -empty-abi-descriptor -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources -module-name CompileFailureTestFramework -frontend-parseable-output -disable-clang-spi -target-sdk-version 16.2 -parse-as-library -num-threads 10 -o /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.o -index-unit-output-path /CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.o

caller: $s27CompileFailureTestFramework19LocalStorageManagerVyACyxq_Gq_cfcfA_
callee: $s27CompileFailureTestFramework19LocalStorageServiceVyACSo13NSFileManagerCcfcfA_
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework.swift -emit-module-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.swiftsourceinfo -emit-dependencies-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-master.d -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-master.dia -emit-objc-header-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework-Swift.h -emit-abi-descriptor-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.abi.json -target arm64-apple-ios16.2-simulator -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk -I /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -no-color-diagnostics -g -module-cache-path /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -serialize-debugging-options -enable-bare-slash-regex -empty-abi-descriptor -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/CompileFailureTestFramework-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/DerivedSources -module-name CompileFailureTestFramework -frontend-parseable-output -disable-clang-spi -target-sdk-version 16.2 -parse-as-library -num-threads 10 -o /Users/youngbinlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompileFailureTestFramework-ftqqxqgzqkusyngesbvylequustq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.o -index-unit-output-path /CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Release-iphonesimulator/CompileFailureTestFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CompileFailureTestFramework.o
1.  Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
2.  Compiling with the current language version
3.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { PrepareOptimizationPasses, EarlyModulePasses, HighLevel,Function+EarlyLoopOpt, HighLevel,Module+StackPromote, MidLevel,Function, ClosureSpecialize, LowLevel,Function, LateLoopOpt, SIL Debug Info Generator } on SIL for CompileFailureTestFramework)
4.  While running pass #1046 SILFunctionTransform "EarlyInliner" on SILFunction "@$s27CompileFailureTestFramework19LocalStorageManagerVyACyxq_Gq_cfcfA_".
 for expression at [/Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework.swift:37:43 - line:37:63] RangeText="LocalStorageService("
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x0000000107a075b0 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 56
1  swift-frontend           0x0000000107a065b4 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 112
2  swift-frontend           0x0000000107a07c34 SignalHandler(int) + 344
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001ae8a02a4 _sigtramp + 56
4  swift-frontend           0x0000000103ac17e4 swift::getEligibleFunction(swift::FullApplySite, swift::InlineSelection) + 1576
5  swift-frontend           0x00000001039b35a0 (anonymous namespace)::SILPerformanceInlinerPass::run() + 2068
6  swift-frontend           0x0000000103908470 swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(unsigned int, unsigned int) + 4020
7  swift-frontend           0x00000001039050c4 swift::SILPassManager::executePassPipelinePlan(swift::SILPassPipelinePlan const&) + 148
8  swift-frontend           0x0000000103920670 swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 56
9  swift-frontend           0x000000010390d858 llvm::Expected<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&) + 504
10 swift-frontend           0x000000010390f9a0 swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 368
11 swift-frontend           0x00000001030c1694 swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 524
12 swift-frontend           0x00000001030525cc performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1064
13 swift-frontend           0x0000000103054ce8 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7284
14 swift-frontend           0x0000000102ff5294 swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 3940
15 dyld                     0x00000001ae547e50 start + 2544
```

#### Insight

- The part I noticed is `[/Users/youngbinlee/Documents/Github/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework/CompileFailureTestFramework.swift:37:43 - line:37:63] RangeText="LocalStorageService("` and `Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var` LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH `to point to it):`
- Thanks to those logs, I could solve the error by changing `init` of `LocalStorageManager`:

```
// Changed
public init(_ localStorage: Storage? = nil) {
        if let localStorage {
            self.localStorage = localStorage
        } else {
            self.localStorage = LocalStorageService() as! Storage
        }
            
        self.coderSet = CoderSet()
    }
```

- It works but I don't know why..

#### Question

So my question is:

- Is there any reason why it doesn't fail in debug, but only in release?
- And why is the original `init` failing to compile?

If you have any idea, please let me know. Thanks!